Ratios when 0 denominator is possible
I've seen a few threads discussing something similar but I feel like my use case is a little different and doesn't fit the answers given.
I have records for digital usage where a user can use the web site or the mobile app or both in a given time period.  The user will always have at least one occurrence for either web or app.  I want to create a label that says something like "always web", "always app", "primarily web", "primarily app", and "even".  In addition to a simple label I also want to observe the "weight" of the ratio - not just is it different, but how drastically?  My thoughts...
Using a ratio of x = web count/app count ...

always web - web count/0 (undefined)
always app - 0/app count (0)
even - I'll probably call anything between 0.9 and 1.1 "even"
primarily  one or the other is < 0.9 or > 1.1

My problem is the first one, always web.  Can anyone suggest a way to create some kind of "weighted" metric to show how/if it's different, as well as how drastic that is?
Thank you!

Just use $\frac {web_count} {(web_count+app_count)}$. Always web is 1, always app is 0, even is 0.5 (and thereabout). No more divide by 0.  Now, whether you can run any statistics on these ratios, whether the results are interpretable, whether even transforming counts into 3 categories, etc. make sense, are all a whole different story.

Thanks, this a good way to rattle it around in my brain.  I still have to figure out the best way to visualize this, but now with this calculation I'm now thinking that I can bucket them in bands of 0.1 and have 10 groups of all-web to all-app.

Not sure what your end purpose is, but whether you have 3 categories, or 10, you are losing a lot of information. You are also distorting it; e.g. a user who just happened happened to use the web only once, will have the same score as a user who used the web 100 times, and a higher score than a user who used the web 80 times, and the app 20... Really? Why not tally accross all the users? Now you have a web/app ratio, with no 0 denominator, and where the user with 1 access does not "weigh" as much as a user with 100...
